# gparted flash drive format

Tags: gparted, format

I want to use gparted to format the flash drive and then burn Ubuntu on it. I downloaded gparted, butI can't find the right way to do so. In found a tutorial for this, and they counseled me to format it to "fat32", but I don't find it this in the options of gparted. When I choose to "create new partitions", I can only choose in the format aix, amiga, bsd, dvh, gpt, mac, msdos, pc98, sun or loop. Which one should I to correctly format the flas drive?

Comment: You do not need to format flash drive to load Ubuntu installer on it. Is that you are trying to do?

Comment: Are you mixing partitioning type with each partitions format. The gpt or msdos are the main partitioning types now used. We use gpt for UEFI and msdos for MBR. Normally flash drive installers can be either, but a few systems do not work with one or the other. Then you can choose to add partitions and format those partitions. But as Pilot6 says you normally do not have to partition the installer in advance as the install software, erases flash drive, formats it(and creates partition type), extracts ISO and makes flash drive bootable.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I have xubuntu already installed on the flash drive and I want to replace it my ubuntu. That's why I have to format it